# Binary search implementation java algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, search, binary

I need help with implementing the binary search algorithm, can someone tell me what's wrong with my code:

```
public int bsearch(Item idToSearch) { 
    int lowerBoundary = 0;
    int upperBoundary = myStore.size() - 1;
    int mid = -1;

    while(upperBoundary >= lowerBoundary) {
        mid = (lowerBoundary + upperBoundary) / 2;

        //if element at middle is less than item to be searched, than set new lower boundary to mid
        if(myStore.get(mid).compareTo(idToSearch) < 0) {
            lowerBoundary = mid - 1;
        } else {
            upperBoundary = mid + 1;
        }
    } //end while loop

    if(myStore.get(mid).equals(idToSearch)) {
        return mid;
    } else {
        return -1; // item not found
    }
} // end method
```

Comment: A debugger could definitely tell you what is wrong.

Comment: a quite incorrect algorithm...

Answer (score 4):

I think you made a mistake when update `lowerBoundary` and `upperBoundary`.

It may be:

```
    if(myStore.get(mid).compareTo(idToSearch) < 0){
        lowerBoundary = mid + 1;
    } else {
        upperBoundary = mid - 1;
    }
```

And why don't you break the loop if you find the element at `mid`?

Answer (score 0):

I would

- stop when the lower and upper bound are the same.
- stop when you find a match
- use `mid = (hi + lo) >>> 1;` to avoid an overflow causing a bug.
- read the code in the JDK which does this already as it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is with the boundaries, also you should stop in case he found the value, but he doesn't which lead to possible overlook.

```
while(upperBoundary >= lowerBoundary)
{
        mid = (lowerBoundary + upperBoundary) / 2;

        if (myStore.get(mid).equals(idToSearch)) break; // goal

        if(myStore.get(mid).compareTo(idToSearch) < 0)
        {
            lowerBoundary = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            upperBoundary = mid - 1;
        }
}
```